# Main <h1> tag is embedded in an unordered list. Will this affect SEO?

Tags: seo, html

By way of design the header of my document looks like this. The `<h1>` is buried in an `<ol>`. It's still the first heading tag of the page but will it lose any of it's SEO value compared to it just sitting on it's own as the first tag of the body?

```
<body>    
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ol>
    <li><h1><a href="">Company Name</a></h1></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
```

Comment: What benefit do you get from doing it this way? It's very non-standard.

Comment: Are you aware that your h1 will be the heading for the nav block and not for the page?

Comment: @Kenzo No benefit, from a layout perspective it was easiest to code this way. Just testing ideas.

Comment: @Rob No I didn't think of that. Good spot. Want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That `<h1>` will be the heading for the `<nav>` section and not the page as a whole. [`<nav>` is its own sectioning element](http://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-nav-element) and won't affect the page's SEO.

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't effect SEO. Use a `<span>` or a `class`, and some CSS.